# Errors While Using IF statement in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query, which returns `tipo_id` from a table, depending on the value of this I want to join with another table, for example if `tipo_id` is 1 I want to join with table called `p_read` if `tipo_id` i want to join `tv_read`

this is what I tried to do.

```
SELECT ec.id,ec.estado,fv.id,fv.num_factura,fv.importe,fv.iva,fv.total,fv.fecha_consumo_inicio,fv.fecha_consumo_fin,
fv.fecha_factura, fv.fichero, c.total, l.tipo_id, lp.id_consumo FROM aldroges8.factura_venta fv
INNER JOIN aldroges8.lectura l ON fv.id=l.facturaVenta_id
INNER JOIN aldroges8.factura_cobro fc ON fc.facturaventa_id = fv.id
INNER JOIN aldroges8.cobros c ON c.id=fc.cobros_id
INNER JOIN aldroges8.estado_cobros ec ON ec.id = c.estado
IF (l.tipo_id=1)
 INNER JOIN aldroges8.lectura_potencia lp ON l.id=lp.id
ELSE IF (l.tipo_id =3)
 INNER JOIN aldroges8.lectura_tv_gas lp ON lp.id=l.id 
WHERE fv.factura_enviada=1 AND fv.suministro_id=:id_contrato ORDER BY fv.fecha_factura DESC;
```

But i am getting this error.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (l.tipo_id==1)
 INNER JOIN aldroges8.lectura_potencia lp ON l.id=lp.id
ELSE' at line 7
```

So I want to know if there is a way on doing this if staments on a query, or do I need to make another query with `tipo_id`, thanks in advance

Comment: You can not use if condition in SQL.

Comment: You can't use IF statements in a query. Do left joins instead.

Comment: @FahadAnjum. we can use if statements in SQL. am very sure of that

Comment: you say use something like `LEFT JOIN aldroges8.lectura_potencia lp ON l.id=lp.id LEFT JOIN aldroges8.lectura_tv_gas lp ON lp.id=l.id` ? @jarlh

Comment: @kishea yes we can use if condition. but only in select clause.

Comment: If statements can be used in stored programs (procedures, functions, triggers, events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this with the condition in the `on` clause and then use `coalesce()` in the `select`:

```
SELECT ec.id, ec.estado, fv.id, fv.num_factura, fv.importe, fv.iva, 
       fv.total, fv.fecha_consumo_inicio, fv.fecha_consumo_fin,
       fv.fecha_factura, fv.fichero, c.total, l.tipo_id, 
       coalesce(lp_1.id_conumo, lp_3.id_consumo)  as id_consumo
FROM aldroges8.factura_venta fv INNER JOIN
     aldroges8.lectura l
     ON fv.id = l.facturaVenta_id INNER JOIN
     aldroges8.factura_cobro fc
     ON fc.facturaventa_id = fv.id INNER JOIN
     aldroges8.cobros c
     ON c.id = fc.cobros_id INNER JOIN
     aldroges8.estado_cobros ec
     ON ec.id = c.estado LEFT JOIN
     aldroges8.lectura_potencia lp_1
     ON l.id = lp_1.id AND l.tipo_id = 1 LEFT JOIN
     aldroges8.lectura_tv_gas lp_3
     ON lp_3.id = l.id AND l.tipo_id = 3
WHERE fv.factura_enviada = 1 AND
      fv.suministro_id = :id_contrato
ORDER BY fv.fecha_factura DESC;
```

The difference between doing the comparison in the `ON` verses in a `CASE` expression may seem subtle, but it can be important.

If there are multiple matches in either table, then putting the condition in the `SELECT` will result in duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ec.id,ec.estado,fv.id,fv.num_factura,fv.importe,fv.iva,fv.total,fv.fecha_consumo_inicio,fv.fecha_consumo_fin,
fv.fecha_factura, fv.fichero, c.total, l.tipo_id, 
/* Used case when statement to get the required result in that column */ 
case when l.tipo_id=1 then lp_1.id_consumo 
     when l.tipo_id=3 then lp_3.id_consumo end  as id_consumo
FROM aldroges8.factura_venta fv
INNER JOIN aldroges8.lectura l ON fv.id=l.facturaVenta_id
INNER JOIN aldroges8.factura_cobro fc ON fc.facturaventa_id = fv.id
INNER JOIN aldroges8.cobros c ON c.id=fc.cobros_id
INNER JOIN aldroges8.estado_cobros ec ON ec.id = c.estado
left join  aldroges8.lectura_potencia lp_1 ON l.id=lp_1.id
left join aldroges8.lectura_tv_gas lp_3 ON lp_3.id=l.id 
WHERE fv.factura_enviada=1 AND fv.suministro_id=:id_contrato ORDER BY fv.fecha_factura DESC;
```

Comment: Should include in your answer a clarification that you're assuming `lp_1` and `lp_3` have 0 or 1 matching rows; thus justifying your `LEFT JOIN` and allowing you to elaborate that if they match many times the you get horrible duplication.

Comment: This made the query work, but I am not getting the right information, I am getting `id_consumo` null while in my table its not null

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks. I will take that into consideration.

Comment: @JaimeCuellar yes, it will show column value null if l.tipo_id is other than 1 and 3. If you want only 1 and 3 then add filter in your where clause

Comment: @JaimeCuellar : Please update your question with an example after reading this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  By using a simplified example with dummy data you can show us which cases you're getting the wrong results for.  *(As it stands I don't believe you're getting a NULL results for a NOT NULL value in the table, **something else** is the actual problem : Such as `l.tipo_id` being `1` but the value you want being in `lectura_tv_gas`.)*

Comment: I was reading the data wrong, sorry about taht comment, those `null` values are correct, but now i've tried this, but I need a little bit more of help, if `l.tipo_id=1` I want to get `lp_1.precio` and if `l.tipo_id=3` i want to get lp_3.consmokw, i've tried this `case when l.tipo_id=1 then lp_1.precio when l.tipo_id=3 then lp_3.cosumokw end as consumokw` in my query but i am getting error @FahadAnjum

Comment: I had sintax error, but got it working, I am getting this as result `"tipo_id": "3","consumokw": "0.00"` while my `consumokw` should be `227.62` i am getting more that 1 element with the query but they all having `consumokw` 0 @FahadAnjum

Comment: i've checked and i am getting that from another field, it should be from `l.id` that is `1145145` but insted i am getting it from `l.id=4054461`

Comment: Please add the sample data which will help us to check your query as well.

Comment: this is the response, ` "id": "1145145", "estado":"Cobrado","num_factura": "G18-0024345","importe": "44.4597" "iva": "9.34", "total":"53.80","fecha_consumo_inicio":"2018-01-23", "fecha_consumo_fin": "2018-03-20", "fecha_factura": "2018-04-15", "fichero": "15G31000499_042018_G18-0024345.pdf","tipo_id": "3","alv": "4054461"` `alv` is `lp_3.id`

Comment: Please create a new question with the table structure in it provide sample the data as well,

Comment: I was doing one `ON` wrong, it worked, thanks for the help

Comment: sorry to ask again, what if i want to get more data from each table, i tried this but error `case when l.tipo_id=1 then lp_1.precio, lp_1.pot_contratada when l.tipo_id=3 then lp_3.consumokw, lp_3.factor end as data1,data2` how would I add more fields to return? @FahadAnjum

Comment: @JaimeCuellar - Read the link I gave you, create an example that only includes what you need, raise a new question with that Minimal Complete  Verifiable Example.